# jquery submitHandler wp_ajax action not working - Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm validating and then submitting the values .

The ajax action is not working here.

Please have an look on the code.

Please help out!!!!!!

```
function et_contact_form() {  ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
 jQuery("#contact_modal").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        msg: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your name",
        msg: "Please enter a short message, what your inquiry is about"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        var name    = jQuery("#name").val();
        var data    = {
                   'action':'et_contact_modal',
                   'dname'  : name 
                  };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });

    }

    });
  });

</script> <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'et_contact_form' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below code for ajex call function

```
function et_contact_form() {  ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     jQuery("#contact_modal").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            msg: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name",
            msg: "Please enter a short message, what your inquiry is about"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var contact_modal_ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            var name    = jQuery("#name").val();
            var contact_modal_str = '&action=et_contact_modal&dname='+name;
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: contact_modal_ajaxurl,
                data: contact_modal_str,
                success: function(data){
                    var contact_modal_responsedata = jQuery(data);
                     alert(contact_modal_responsedata);

                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }

            });
            return false;  // block the default submit action

        }

    });
});
</script> 
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'et_contact_form' ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue found!!

The above code works when admin is logged in only ,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_et_contact_modal', 'et_contact_modal' );
```

Added an action if the admin is not logged in ,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_et_contact_modal', 'et_contact_modal' );
```